# How could we exclude or hide part of the values in one dict field in the nested dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have two python dataclass

```
@dataclass
class Grade:
    school: str = "school_default"
    classroom: str = "classroom_default"
    score: dict = field(default_factory= {'total':{'Math':100, 'English': 90, 'Chemistry':95, 'Password':11111}}, repr=True)
```

The field of the second dataclass is using the first dataclass as:

```
@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str = "Alice"
    age:  int = field(default=10, repr=False)
    sex:  str = 'female'
    grade: Grade = None
```

If I initialize the Student dataclass as followed:

```
s1 = Student('Jimmy', 20, 'Male', Grade('school2', 'classroom2', {'total':{'Math':99, 'English':88, 
'Chemistry':77, 'Password':33333}}))
```

It will print out s1 instance as

```
Student(name='Jimmy', sex='Male', grade=Grade(school='school2', classroom='classroom2', score={'total': {'Math': 99, 
'English': 88, 'Chemistry': 77, 'Password': 33333}}))
```

How could I EXCLUDE or HIDE the sensitive data e.g Password and Chemistry fields when printing out the Student dataclass?

I want it will be printed out as:

```
Student(name='Jimmy', sex='Male', grade=Grade(school='school2', classroom='classroom2', score={'total': {'Math': 99, 
'English': 88, 'Chemistry': '******', 'Password': '******'}}))
```

I have tried to use

```
field(repr=False)
```

or overwrite the **str** method as

```
    def __str__(self):
        str_info = {
            k: v if k not in ['grade'] and v else '******' for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
        }
        return str(str_info)
```

But it will hide the whole grade value instead of Password and Chemistry

```
{'name': 'Jimmy', 'age': 20, 'sex': 'Male', 'grade': '******'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to hide sensitive information and use it to rewrite the `__repr__` method of `Grade`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

def hide_sensitive(score: dict):
    res = {}
    for k,v in score.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res[k] = hide_sensitive(v)
        elif k in ['Chemistry', 'Password']:
            res[k] = '******'
        else:
             res[k] = v
    return res

@dataclass
class Grade:
    school: str = "school_default"
    classroom: str = "classroom_default"
    score: dict = field(default_factory={'total':{'Math':100, 'English': 90, 'Chemistry':95, 'Password':11111}})

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Grade(school={self.school}, classroom={self.classroom}, score={hide_sensitive(self.score)})'

@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str = "Alice"
    age:  int = field(default=10, repr=False)
    sex:  str = 'female'
    grade: Grade = None


s1 = Student('Jimmy', 20, 'Male', Grade('school2', 'classroom2', {'total':{'Math':99, 'English':88, 'Chemistry':77, 'Password':33333}}))

print(s1)
```

Output:

```
Student(name='Jimmy', sex='Male', grade=Grade(school=school2, classroom=classroom2, score={'total': {'Math': 99, 'English': 88, 'Chemistry': '******', 'Password': '******'}}))
```

Note that printing `s1.grade.score` won't hide sensitive information. If you want to achieve that you can define a `Score` class with its own `__repr__` method that will directly print the output of `hide_sensitive`.

Comment: Wow, it works....., Thanks for your help, Tranbi. Two followed questions: 1. In the Grade dataclass,  implement __repr__, it works. But if I use same code with __str__ in Grade class, it does not hide the value. Why?  2. Is it possible to implement __repr__ in Student dataclass to get same result? ( Hide the Password and Chemistry) in Grade class?

Comment: 1. Because by default, the repr/print for Student will print repr for all attributes. If you define a custom __str__ for `Grade`, it will only work if you print `s1.grade`.
2. You could but why would you do that? It would be more verbose: you would have to format not only grade but name and sex too.

Comment: 1. Got it, thanks; 2. Totally agree. At the beginning, I try to overwrite __str__ and __repr__ in Student class, but it was more difficult. Thanks for your kind help, Tranbi.